# SQL Query with join not updating column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I'm attempting to update my `transactions` table by comparing the `tran_num` and seeing if it is between the `start_tran_num` and `end_tran_num` of the eod_master while also having the `clinic` column value's being the same.

```
UPDATE transactions
SET time_ran=e.time_ran
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN eod_master e
ON e.clinic=t.clinic
WHERE (t.tran_num BETWEEN e.start_tran_num AND e.end_tran_num)
```

This is the script I've attempted to run, however it is not update any values. The query runs endlessly without any updates. Running the following query shows the results I would expect, but can't seem to adapt into an UPDATE query.

```
SELECT t.tran_num, t.clinic, e.time_ran
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN eod_master e
ON e.clinic=t.clinic
WHERE (t.tran_num BETWEEN e.start_tran_num AND e.end_tran_num)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have index on `transactions` table

Comment: Yes, there's a primary key set that increments by 1 for each row introduced

Comment: There needs to be a `BETWEEN` filter which you can't use with `ON` previously attempted using a `CROSS JOIN` but apparently that wasn't proper

Comment: Why couldn't you use the `BETWEEN` in the `JOIN` clause? There's nothing wrong with doing that. My guess is that your syntax was incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the table alias for the `update`:

```
UPDATE t
-------^
    SET time_ran=e.time_ran
FROM transactions t INNER JOIN
     eod_master e
     ON e.clinic = t.clinic AND
        (t.tran_num BETWEEN e.start_tran_num AND e.end_tran_num);
```

It is running endlessly because there is an implicit `cross join`.  If you hadn't killed the query, then it would have updated all rows in `transactions` with some value.

Answer (score 0):

You say it runs endlessly, does that mean you never let it finish?

```
UPDATE transactions
SET time_ran=e.time_ran
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN eod_master e
ON e.clinic=t.clinic
WHERE (t.tran_num BETWEEN e.start_tran_num AND e.end_tran_num)
```

This query would update every single record in Transactions. That is not likely what you want to do and could be why the update goes on endlessly.

```
UPDATE t
SET time_ran=e.time_ran
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN eod_master e
ON e.clinic=t.clinic
WHERE (t.tran_num BETWEEN e.start_tran_num AND e.end_tran_num)
and t.time_ran<>e.time_ran or (t.time_ran is not and e.time_ran) is not null
```

This would only update records that need the update. That might be your problem.

Comment: The first does worse than update every single record.  It updates every single record for every row returned by the `FROM` clause -- hence the really bad performance.